# Put Extra boolen in android give wrong value

Tags: android, boolean

I just weird, why i got wrong value after put extra boolean. Very weird. I know other post already answer about put extra, but this post i don't know why i got wrong value.

This is my first activity. Just short code.

```
btnActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySecond.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1)
    {
        boolean thisAnwser = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("thisAnwserBoolean",false);
        Log.i("this boolean is","Answer: "+thisAnwser); //this log, i got false..

        if(thisAnwser){
            Log.i("Good this true","yes");
        }


    }
}
```

This is second activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("thisAnwserBoolean", true); // when i try log, i got true.
setResult(1,intent);
finish();
```

Comment: You're looking at the wrong `Intent`. You want to get the extras from the `Intent data` parameter in the `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: yes, u are right .. Thanks Sir

Comment: `Bundle extra=data.getExtras();
boolean thisAnwser = extra.getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");

or 
boolean thisAnwser = data.getExtras().getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");`

Answer (score 2):

```
 boolean thisAnswer = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");
```

You are adding a `false`, so you will always get `false`. Remove the `false`

Comment: I also try like this one, same still got false

Comment: Thanks but i already got the answer , this one
`Bundle extra=data.getExtras();
boolean thisAnwser = extra.getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");

or 
boolean thisAnwser = data.getExtras().getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");`

Comment: Great you solved it.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Boolean yourBool = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("yourBoolName");
```

Comment: Thanks but i already got the answer.. This one `Bundle extra=data.getExtras();
boolean thisAnwser = extra.getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");

or 
boolean thisAnwser = data.getExtras().getBoolean("thisAnwserBoolean");`